# Appcelerator ios & windows bridge

Tags: ios, windows-phone-8.1, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I read recently, that MS launched public beta of Windows Bridge - tool that can convert existing iOS application to Universal Windows app. I tried it on Hyper-V virual machine(Win10 required) and it converted my app, but when I try to build it, it throws error:
'AvailabilityInternal.h' file not found @ myApp_Prefix.ch Line 12

Have you anybody tried this out? I think this can be good solution to port iOS apps created with Appcelerator Studio to WP without complete recoding.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've no experience with using Windows Bridge, but why not just build your Titanium app for Windows Phone directly? Titanium supports Windows Phone 8.1 since Titanium 5.0 and the release in Q2 (5.3) will add support for Windows 10 Universal.

See this guide:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Installing_the_Windows_Phone_SDK

Comment: Hi Fokke, I have some problems with Windows support directly in Titanium(f.e https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20192) so I tried new way.

Comment: Fortunately this ticket has been resolved in Titanium 5.2, so please give it another try.